# Highlight those two cells of which it is not same in one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

So, I have this excel 2016 spreadsheet with half million rows in which D2 is equal to D3, D4 is equal to D5 and D6 is equal to D7 and so on. But in some instances like D12 and D13, those two dates are not equal. Can anybody let me know how to highlight those two values which one has the different date to each other? Any formula or something? Difficult to do one by one

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwzCh.pn)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you wish to flag any rows where the charge effective end date is different between the Discount and the Monthly fee

Try this in a blank column on row 3, then drag it down to the end of your data:

```
=IF(AND($B2=$B3, $D2=$D3), "", False)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, select `cell E2`, then go to `Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Format only cells that contain`, and in the fields below, choose `Cell Value`, `not equal to`, `=$D2`, and pick the format you want to display.  You can follow the pic below.

[image]

Then under `Conditional Formatting Rules Manager`, change the `Applies to` to `=$E$2:$E$100` (remember to apply to any cell that you want to have this feature).  Click `Ok` or `Apply` and you should see the results like below.

[image]

Try and let me know.